# how do I restrict belongs_to to only a specific type of user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to set a `belongs_to` association on my Model, eg:

```
belongs_to :user
```

but I want to restrict this to only a type of user (e.g. where `user.role == "admin"`

I have tried to use `belongs_to :user, -> { where(role: "admin") }`, but it does not seem to be working.

any other type of user won't be able to have this association.

how can I go about this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a validation on the comment model

```
class Comment < ...

validate :user_is_admin

private

def user_is_admin
  errors.add(:user, "user must be admin") unless user && user.is_admin?
end

end
```